# Vercel NodeJS server goes to sleep with schedule job scheduled

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel

I'm running a schedule job on button click from my frontend App sent to Nextjs (NodeJS) backend /api/ function which doesn't get triggered upon sending another request...
Does anyone have an idea how could I persist NodeJS server to execute function at the given time without going to sleep and the need to send another request to it?

```
const job = schedule.scheduleJob(
                  buildingName,
                  endBuildTime,
                  function () {
                    console.log("Execute update!");
                  }
             )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serverless functions (Next.js API routes) have an [execution timeout](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions#execution-timeout), which is [`10 seconds` on the hobby plan](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#general-limits).

After `10 seconds`, your function will be killed if it is still processing. Which is what is happening to your function. You are scheduling a job but that job will never execute because the function has been killed.

Comment: I had an idea that something like that was happening yeah, thanks.
Do you maybe know what should I do instead of that to make it work?